# Добавление метода к переменной с помощью записи «через точку» создает в обьекте новое свойство?

Tags: javascript

Насколько я понял запись через точку означает, что к объекту добавляем какое-то свойство с определенным значением:

Вот например:

```
function User (argname) {
  this.name = argname;
}

let user = new User ( "Вася")
```

Здесь мы благодаря записи через точку добавили к объекту User свойство name и присвоили значение аргумента argname.

А вот другой пример:

```
var button = document.getElementById ( "myBtn")

button.onclick = function () {
  newWindow.style.display = "block";
}
```

Здесь после переменной button через точку написали метод onclick. По аналогии с предыдущим примером button- должно быть объектом, onclick- это свойство которое мы добавили к этому объекту, а анонимная функция - это значение свойства.

и по идее обьект должен быть примерно таким:

```
button = {
  onclick: function () {
    newWindow.style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

Правильно?

А если не так, то как?

Поправьте меня если неправильно понимаю. Хочется понять как все работает в JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так. Только свойств и методов у HTML элемента несколько сотен, а свойство `onclick` существовало до Вашего присваивания с значением `null`.